# Why do I get a compilation warning here (var args method call in Java)

Tags: java

Source:

```
public class TestVarArgs {
  public void varArgsMethod(Object ... arr) {
     System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName());
     for(Object o : arr) {
       System.out.println(o);
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestVarArgs tva = new TestVarArgs();
    tva.varArgsMethod(args);    
  }
}
```

Compile:

```
javac TestVarArgs.java
```

Error:

```
TestVarArgs.java:15: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning    
tva.varArgsMethod(args);     
^

1 warning
```

I am using `javac 1.6.0_20` and the code o/p indicates that a non var arg call was made anyways.

Comment: @downvoter please care to comment.Anyway I have balanced it :D

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It is because `String[]` and `Object...` do not exactly match up.

You have to cast the `String[]` to either `Object[]` (if you want to pass the Strings as separate parameters) or `Object` (if you want just one argument that is an array) first.

```
 tva.varArgsMethod((Object[])args);    // you probably want that

 tva.varArgsMethod( (Object) args);    // you probably don't want that, but who knows?
```

Why is this a warning and not an error? Backwards compatibility. Before the introduction of varargs, you had these methods take a `Object[]` and code compiled against that should still work the same way after the method has been upgraded to use varargs. The JDK standard library is full of cases like that. For example `java.util.Arrays.asList(Object[])` has changed to `java.util.Arrays.asList(Object...)` in Java5 and all the old code that uses it should still compile and work without modifications.

Comment: Right,but the compiler chooses a non vararg method call anyways by passing a `String[]`. Why does it do that? Is there a rule around that ? It had the option of doing a var arg call also by sending `new Object[] { String[] }` also. No ?

Comment: Well, but it is kind of ambiguous, so you want to be explicit and avoid the warning.

Answer (score 6):

The argument of type `String[]` should explicitly be cast to `Object[]` for the invocation of the varargs method `varArgsMethod(Object...)` from type TestVarArgs. It could alternatively be cast to Object for a varargs invocation
You can fix it by doing either one of the way
If you cast the `String[]` to `Object[]` (ref:`tva.varArgsMethod((Object[])args);`)
OR
change the parameter of method to `String[]`
(ref:`public void varArgsMethod(String ... paramArr)`)

Comment: You may want to be clear about this. If it is cast to Object[] it will be a non var args invocation.

Comment: @abc focus on the words please.`The argument of type String[] should explicitly be cast to Object[] for the` **`invocation of the varargs method varArgsMethod(Object...)`** and 2nd line ` It could alternatively be cast to Object for a` **`varargs invocation`** So at first I said just for method invocation and 2nd time I said for varargs invocation.But I am agree with you against me that I should explain it more precisely ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this wording is absolutely confusing. If it would not be so confusing, I won't search for this error on SO at the first place. Both phrases "invocation of the varargs method" and "varargs invocation" sound exactly the same for me. Much better would be to say - if you want decomposition of the array into different arguments, cast to Object[]. If you want the whole array to be a single argument - cast to Object.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the method as

```
public void varArgsMethod(String ... arr)
```

Comment: He needs to cast the desired parameter when calling the method.

Comment: He changed `Object...` to `String...`. This would work, but only IF he can change the method (ie. it is his own class/method) and IF the method does never need anything else beeing passed, other than Strings.

Answer (score 0):

The casts to Object and Object[] did not work out for me, it broke my code, resulting in "Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.String (n/a)]" and other randomness.

My line that showed the warning (subj) is the following, where filter.getStates() is of type String[]

p.add(root.join(DeviceEntity_.state, JoinType.LEFT).get(ClassifierEntity_.CODE).in(filter.getStates()));

The solution that worked is to use Arrays.asList(filter.getStates()) instead of casting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the warning message is very confusing indeed, so best to try an example. I tested the two possibilities (cast to `Object` vs `Object[]`) with jshell:

```java
void printVarArgs(String msg, Object obj, Object... args) {
  System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s%n", msg, obj, java.util.Arrays.deepToString(args));
}
```

Here are the results of the 3 kinds of invocation:

1. No casting:

```
jshell> printVarArgs("Foo", 1, new String[] {"a", "b"})
Foo, 1, [a, b]
|  Warning:
|  non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
|    cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
|    cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
|  printVarArgs("Foo", 1, new String[] {"a", "b"})
|                         ^---------------------^
```

2. Cast to `Object`:

```
jshell> printVarArgs("Foo", 1, (Object)(new String[] {"a", "b"}))
Foo, 1, [[a, b]]
```

3. Cast to `Object[]`:

```
jshell> printVarArgs("Foo", 1, (Object[])(new String[] {"a", "b"}))
Foo, 1, [a, b]
```

##### Conclusion:

If you cast a `String[]`-valued argument to `Object` when invoking the method, the method sees a single "var-arg" (i.e. the `Object... args` parameter becomes an array containing a nested `String[]` as its only element), and in our example, prints it as `[[a, b]]`.

If you cast it to `Object[]`, the method gets 2 "var-args" (`"a"` and `"b"`) and prints the `args` parameter as `[a, b]`.  This is exactly the same as the original invocation without an explicit cast.  The only benefit of casting to `Object[]` is the suppression of the compiler warning.

Answer (score -3):

One of the elegant ways to get rid off this warning:
instead of 
  `tva.varArgsMethod(args)`
call
  `tva.varArgsMethod(Arrays.stream(args).toArray())`
explicitly showing that you pass multiple arguments.
Another way to get rid off the warning is to use following call:

```
tva.varArgsMethod(Arrays.asList(args).toArray())
```

Anyway we have to convert the args to Array.

Comment: This a very expensive way to make a copy of the data. A simple cast as shown in other answers would be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Number of arguments passed to a program normally is very small, 1-5 args. By such sizes of the input we can neglect performance issues, elegance and readability here is more important.

Comment: Still, the solution is still slower than necessary. It's also conceptually much more complicated (more classes, more functions). The accepted answer avoids all of these, and comes with literally zero drawbacks, so why would this answer have any value to anybody?