# Is it possible to pass null array to Java varargs?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code in Java:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkVarargs(null);
  }

  public static void checkVarargs(String... o) {
    System.out.println(o);
  }
```

When I try to auto-convert the main method to Kotlin I get the following:

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      checkVarargs(null)
    }
```

However, In the Java case a null array is passed, and it prints `null` while on Kotlin case it prints `[Ljava.lang.String;@548c4f57` (array that contains null).

Is it possible to pass null array to Java varargs from Kotlin code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667573/why-do-i-get-a-compilation-warning-here-var-args-method-call-in-java Or at least the answer gives insight into why

Comment: In the Kotlin case it isn't an empty array, it's an array containing a single `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, why does Java behave like this? Does it make sense? Don't you want to pass a `null` String rather? 
Kotlin doesn't support this vague concept of "nullable varargs", you cannot achieve it as you could in Java.

`checkVarargs()` will pass an empty array

`checkVarargs(null)` will pass an array with `null` in it

Comment: The only reason I want to do it is that I have code in Java and tests in Kotlin and I want to make sure this edge case is covered. If it's not possible I will write this test in Java.

Comment: I tried using the spread operator `checkVarargs(*(null as Array<String>?))` but it gives "The spread operator (*foo) may not be applied to an argument of nullable type". So it does seem to be impossible.